# Angular Bootstrap accordion animation is not working on close in production

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have installed Bootstrap on my app in Angular but for some reason when i am in production after i run `ng build --configuration production` and open it to local server the bootstrap accordion animation does not work on close. The animation works perfectly when i open the accordion but on close does not work. Any solution about this case.

Here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "theme-switcher",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~11.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1101.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.2"
  }
}
```

Here is my `angular.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "7352546f-427c-4086-beae-9a75be929da6"
  },
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "theme-switcher": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/theme-switcher",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/style.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "theme-switcher:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "theme-switcher:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "theme-switcher:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "theme-switcher:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "theme-switcher:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "theme-switcher"
}
```

Here is my `style.scss`

```
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Here is my `app.component.html`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="accordion" id="accordionPanelsStayOpenExample">
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne">
          Accordion Item #1
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingTwo">
        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo">
          Accordion Item #2
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingTwo">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingThree">
        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseThree">
          Accordion Item #3
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingThree">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Same problem in my case. Occurs only when optimization and buildOptimizer flags are both true. Did you find the solution?

Comment: @RafałGąsior I have not found any solution yet

Comment: Hi, [here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/accordion) my angular-bootstrap-accordion-component, [here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-animations/src/lib/slide-up-down.animation.ts) an awesome slide-up-down animation (which requires the `BrowserAnimationsModule` at root level) and [here's](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/basic/accordion) a demo

Answer (score 3):

It looks that this is a bug in an Angular JavaScript optimizer.
I have already reported an in issue to Angular team: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22635

Options you have until Angular team fixes this one:

1. Exclude bootstrap.js script from angular injection and add bootstrap.js manually in main html file of your app by yourself:

- Edit your angular.json file and change

```
"scripts": [
   "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
]
```

to:

```
"scripts": [
  {"input" :"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js",
   "inject": false
  }
]
```

- Inject flag set to false prevents file to be included in final angular JavaScript file. You can also remove bootstrap.js from your angular.json, but then there will be no trace of bootstrap's JavaScript file anywhere in Angular. Leaving that line will make you to remember about reverting this change after a proper fix from Angular team.
- Edit your main html file (e.g. index.html) and add bootstrap.js there. It has to be added at the bottom of html file as it has to be loaded as latest as possible:

```
...
</body>
    <script src="dist/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

With this approach there is an additional request from browser for bootstra.ks file but at least it has it's own optimized versions which you can reference (like in the example above).

2. Replace Bootstrap's collapsing functionality with [(ngCollapse)] directive from ngBootstrap package. I found that this one is not affected by closing animation bug. To do that you have to install version of ngBootstrap which is valid for your Angular/Bootstrap mix and replace "data-bs-toggle" attributes with [(ngCollapse)] directive. More on that can be found here:
   https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples

Comment: This is a great answer, but I found with option 1. that the bootstrap bundle added to the dist folder (with inject:false) has still been through optimisations and fails to function for me using Angular 13.0.0, and I have to manually copy the bootstrap.bundle.min.js file over to the dist folder for the animation to work.  I have a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71903388/angular-13-0-0-possible-build-issue-with-bootstrap-5-1-3-carousel-transition-a

Comment: Also, what if you want to use it in TypeScript? As soon as bootstrap is imported as a module, Angular 'helpfully' includes it and optimises it and so it breaks animations again

Comment: @SingleEntity When I want to use some functions from bootstrap in TypeScript I just import them using somtething following (or similar, depending on which Bootstrap element I'm using): **import {NgbActiveModal, NgbDateAdapter, NgbDateParserFormatter, NgbDateStruct} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';**

As for optimizations - I've just checked and inject: false properly works on my side. I'm using Angular 13 and Bootstrap 5.1.