# Angular 13.0.0 possible build issue with Bootstrap 5.1.3 - carousel transition animations do not work properly when built using ng build

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

As per the title, running Angular 13.0.0 and Bootstrap 5.1.3, the animations are broken for carousel transitions when the Angular application is built for production using `ng build` and hosted on localhost as static files via nginx.

The animations and transitions work fine however when using `ng serve` (the dev server that comes with Angular).

HTML straight out of the Bootstrap 5 examples but with links for the images

```
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="https://www.primrose.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/acf06ef1ca6b6cd54f153540f7686931/P/L/PL9239062__main_image_ce07.jpg"
                class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://www.primrose.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/acf06ef1ca6b6cd54f153540f7686931/P/L/PL9239062__add_image_1_9078.jpg"
                class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://www.primrose.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/acf06ef1ca6b6cd54f153540f7686931/P/L/PL9239062__main_image_ce07.jpg"
                class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

angular.json containing bootstrap and popperjs

```
    {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "carouselTest": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/carouselTest",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "carouselTest:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "carouselTest:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "carouselTest:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "carouselTest"
}
```

Just for completeness, package.json:

```
{
  "name": "carousel-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.0.0-next.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.0.0-next.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.0.0-next.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.0.0-next.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.0.0-next.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.0.0-next.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.0.0-next.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.0.0-next.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.3.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.0.0-next.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.4.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using bootstrap.min.js and popper.min.js in angular.json,
use bootstrap.bundle.min.js in index.html